# Oracle select CLOB column still has line break even after using chr(10) and chr(13)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, line-breaks, clob

I have the following queries:

Query 1:

```
   select column1, column2 from table1 where column1 = 12345;
```

Results 1:

```
 column1|column2 
   12345|Topics briefed:
        |1) How to catch a fish
        |without using a fishing rod
        |2) How to cook a fish
```

Query 2:

```
select column1, REPLACE(REPLACE(column2, chr(10), ''), chr(13), '') as col2 from table1 where column1 = 12345;
```

Results 2:

```
 column1|col2 
   12345|Topics briefed: 1) How to catch a fish
        |without using a fishing rod 2) How to cook a fish
```

Results 2 is not what I wanted, I want everything to be in one row. How can I achieve the following results:

```
 column1|col2 
   12345|Topics briefed: 1) How to catch a fish without using a fishing rod 2) How to cook a fish
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you find out by `DUMP(substr(column2, 1, 4000))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you're displaying these results, but my guess is that you actually have stripped out the line breaks, but whatever you're using to display them is wrapping them. If you're in sqlplus, you can do `set linesize 999` to make the line very wide and `column column2 format a200` to make column 2 display 200 characters wide.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would work:

```
select column1, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column2, chr(10), ''), chr(13), ''), chr(09), '') as col2
from table1
where column1 = 12345;
```

Comment: Why would a tab character cause a line break in the output?

Comment: If it's multiple tab characters, then it's possible.